# Calculate the inverted scale to keep a child element the same size after parent element is resized

Tags: javascript, svg

I have an element which contains a number of child elements, I'm scaling using a transform but want to ensure that some  shapes within that element remain the same size - aren't scaled based on the parents transform.

I was wondering if its possible to calculate the scale of an element based on the transform matrix applied?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Call `getScreenCTM()` on the element you want to scale, to get the transform matrix representing its current scale and position.  Call `inverse()` on that matrix. Then apply that inverse matrix to the element.